# Output contents of column from MSSQL in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Trying to output all of the contents of a column from a MSSQL database into an array and at the moment I am getting this as an output:

```
ConsoleApplication3.Program+ClassName
ConsoleApplication3.Program+ClassName
```

if I add an extra row to the column then there will be three of the same thing output. The code that is handling all of this is below.

```
public class ClassName
    {
        public string Col1 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog = Backups; User ID = BackupsU; Password = ; ");
            ClassName[] allRecords = null;
            string sql = @"SELECT company_Name FROM Company";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var list = new List<ClassName>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                        list.Add(new ClassName { Col1 = reader.GetString(0) });
                    allRecords = list.ToArray();

                }

                foreach (var item in allRecords)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the `Col1` property on each instance of your `ClassName` class

```
  foreach (var item in allRecords)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(item.Col1);
  }
```

Without that, you are just calling `Object.ToString()` which unless overridden, will just return the full name of your class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either override `ClassName.ToString()` to return `ClassName.Col1`, or just use `item.Col1` in your Console.Writeline statement.

Since `.ToString` is not overriden it falls back to `Object.ToString()`, which outputs the class name.